# Two execution of MAP in pymc gives different values

Tags: python, distribution, probability, pymc, mcmc

I wanted to learn about MAP optimization im pymc. I got the following posterior distribution of `lambda` after sampling using mcmc
[image]

Clearly, the posterior is maximum at lambda = 0.20 and the 95% intervals are [0.17, 0.24] (please correct me if I am wrong)

As far as I know MAP gives a point estimate (the value of lambda which has max posterior probability ), but when I run MAP twice, I get different values which should not be the case.

I am printing the values of lambda before nd after using map in 2 execution of d same program.

Before using MAP
0.200091865615
After using MAP
0.197584715205

Before using MAP 
1.28960939539
After using MAP
2.70871770586

Can someone explain what is going on and how to get rid of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be convergence issues with the optimizer at the second starting value. Can you try a different optimizer? For example:

```
MAP(method='fmin_powell')
```

Comment: But how do I know in advance that I will have to use some other optimizer ? I already had the posterior, hence I could verify  here but that might not be the case everytime.

Comment: You don't. The art behind optimization is being able to choose a reasonable starting value. You can do this in PyMC by setting the `value=` argument (otherwise it uses a random draw).